# What gates is Anna referring to?

Tags: frozen-ii

Anna speaks to Olaf:

> Anna: well, I have you and Elsa and Kristoff and Sven... and **the gates**
> are open wide...and I'm not alone anymore.

What "gates" is Anna referring to?

Comment: See the second musical number from the first film.

Comment: https://frozen.fandom.com/wiki/Gates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is referencing the original [Frozen](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/Frozen). After Elsa injured Anna with magic as a child, their father shut down the castle to minimize Elsa’s contact with people while her powers were dangerous:

> **King:** No. We'll protect her. She can learn to control it. I'm sure. Until then, we'll lock the gates. We'll reduce the staff. We will limit her contact with people, and keep her powers hidden from everyone. Including Anna.

The gates can be seen at around 2:50 during [“For the First Time in Forever”](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrX1XKtShSI), when they open on the day of Elsa’s coronation.

[image]